# Integration of Spring, Hibernate and JSF

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf

We are developing project, in that main requirement is by using `JSF` and `Hibernate` but We want develop it with Hibernate, JSF and Spring.

We just want to know that what are the advantages and disadvantages by using three framework or is it right way to develop using integration of three?

Comment: Hello, you've got many tutorials in the net that describe the three frameworks, and many of them provide instructions for integration. Have you already gone through them?

Comment: Yes....i have gone but not proper tutorial i got, can you share some link of them?

Comment: Spring docs have instructions on how to integrate with JSF. Regarding to hibernate, it is a first class citizen in Spring.

Comment: But both spring and hibernate have standardized counterparts, CDI and JPA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring offers you uniform way to control dependencies between your objects. This is called inversion of control or dependency injection. Using it you can create pluggable, testable code that is easy to maintain.

In addition it gives you gazillion utility classes that just make life easier. For example, Hibernate is much easier to maintain via Spring facilities. It kind of brings together many different technologies under the same roof. Spring with Hibernate has been one of the most preferred architecture for last few years for developing Java web application.

Now coming to JSF, JSF is framework for dynamically generating HTML on the server side. There you can dynamically generate HTML elements directly based on your Java objects.
The JSF model has fallen out of favour. It is viewed as a legacy framework against today’s Javascript frameworks with RESTful API backend’s. This has moved the Java to implementing the RESTful microservices. This approach can often scale better than JSF.

The key strength of JSF lies in the component frameworks in the JSF ecosystem. In particular PrimeFaces, or the utility libraries like omnifaces. They let you quickly get started on projects, have plenty examples and are especially suited in a team or for projects where developers lack frontend skills. The deployment model is often simple, with a single war or ear file per server.

So taking in account scalability I would recommend you to go with Spring Boot Rest Servies+ Hibernate + AngularJs/ReactJs.

Comment: does JSF and Hibernate give flexibility?

Comment: Flexibility as in what? Hibernate is an ORM framework, there are alternatives to HIbernate, you should decide according to your requirements. JSF is a frontend framwork and it is critised for not being fexible.

Comment: _"This has moved the Java to implementing the RESTful microservices. This approach can often scale better than JSF."_ Scaling for facebook like number of users. For more normal applications, the advantage is very little compared to the speed you can get for developing on JSF (assuming you know a little more than the basics) Personally I'd drop Spring for CDI (standardized) and JPA2.1 instead of direct Hibernate. Works great for me

Comment: @Kukeltje You are right and that is the reason architects have a job to do as you have many factors involved while deciding. Jyoti, I recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739099/how-to-design-and-architect-a-java-java-ee-web-application